# Webpack - handling required stylesheets in server-side rendering

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side

In my React/Webpack app, I am having a problem where my HTML is not referencing the included stylesheets - I have a basic understanding of why this is happening, but I don't quite get the specifics and I definitely don't know the best way to solve the problem. Here's the lowdown...

My app uses server-side rendering, and I have two separate Webpack configurations, one for the client (`webpack.config.js`) and one for the server (`webpack.server.config.js`). In my app components, I `require()` two stylesheets that come from Node modules like so:

```
require("bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css")
require("react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css")
```

and these are compiled into a separate stylesheet (`public/css/vendor/main.css`) via Webpack's `ExtractTextPlugin`.  Here's the client-side `webpack.config`:

```
const webpack = require("webpack"),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin"),
    webpackConfig = {
        "entry": "./src/index.jsx",
        "module": {
            "loaders": [
                {
                    "exclude": /node_modules/,
                    "loader": "babel-loader",
                    "query": { "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"] },
                    "test": /\.jsx?$/
                },
                {
                    "exclude": /node_modules/,
                    "loader": "babel-loader",
                    "test": /\.js$/
                },
                {
                    "loader": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        "fallback": "style-loader",
                        "use": "css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[local]"
                    }),
                    "test": /\.css$/
                },
                {
                    "loader": "file-loader?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]",
                    "test": /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/
                }
            ]
        },
        "output": {
            "filename": "./public/bundle.js",
            "publicPath": "/"
        },
        "plugins": [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "API_URL": JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL || "http://localhost:4000/api/v1"),
                "IS_STAGING": JSON.stringify(process.env.IS_STAGING || "false"),
                "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || "development")
            }),
            new ExtractTextPlugin({
                filename: "public/css/vendor/[name].css",
                disable: false,
                allChunks: true
            })
        ]
    }

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

So far, so good. In fact, if I run my app in development mode (which doesn't use my `webpack.server.config` but rather `babel-register` to handle server-side compilation 'on the fly'), the HTML is styled correctly. However, when I run a production build, which uses `webpack.server.config.js` to build a server-side bundle, that's where the trouble starts.  Here's `webpack.server.config.js`, which includes code that I'm sure is incorrect:

```
const webpack = require("webpack"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    path = require("path"),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    "entry": path.resolve(__dirname, "index.js"),
    "externals": fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")).concat(["react-dom/server", "react/addons"]).reduce((ext, mod) => {
        ext[mod] = `commonjs ${mod}`
        return ext
    }, {}),
    "module": {
        "loaders": [
            {
                "exclude": /node_modules/,
                "loader": "babel-loader",
                "query": { "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"] },
                "test": /\.jsx$/
            },
            {
                "exclude": /node_modules/,
                "loader": "babel-loader",
                "query": { "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"] },
                "test": /\.js$/
            },
            {
                "loader": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    "fallback": "style-loader",
                    "use": "css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[local]"
                }),
                "test": /\.css$/
            },
            {
                "loader": "file-loader?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]",
                "test": /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/
            }
        ]
    },
    "node": {
        "__dirname": true,
        "__filename": true
    },
    "output": {
        "filename": "server.bundle.js"
    },
    "target": "node",
    "plugins": [
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
            "GIT_COMMIT": "No git commit hash provided",
            "BUILD_DATE": "No build date provided"
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "public/css/vendor/[name].css",
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        })
    ],
}
```

For reference, the `build` command is:

```
"build:client": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
"build:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js",
"build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server"
```

The problem is the reuse of the `ExtractTextPlugin` and `file-loader`. When this code is used to build the server-side configuration there are no errors thrown, but the stylesheets don't apply to the HTML when I start the app (even though they are present). Now I'm fairly certain that this redundancy is what's causing the problem - I did a test where I left the server config out and the app worked perfectly, although I lost the benefits of server-side rendering, which I need - but I don't understand the best way to resolve this.

Because of the `require()`s in my components, the server-side Webpack is looking for those and needs to know what to do with them, but simply reusing the `ExtractTextPlugin` (as in the client-side config) causes the styling to fail, even though the files are present when the app runs.

What is the best course of action for addressing this?  Is my question/problem clear?

Comment: I dont think creating a server side bundle for your css/scss/sass is the correct approach, as you only need the compiled class module names from it, have you checked out something like `css-modules-require-hook`? basically it mimics what the classes names in the SSR'd file are supposed to be (preproccess), then since your client side bundle is built correctly by webpack, it should technically just work. And if your NODE_ENV is production, the require statements should be cached by default. I have built a couple apps with this approach and they are crazy fast. Hopefully your using a js backend.

Comment: @Marrs thanks for taking the time to share your expertise - what you're describing sounds exactly like what I'm looking for (and yes, JS backend). I'll let you know if I can get that to work.

Comment: Let me know how it goes!